# Fetching records from inside a JSON Object inside an Array

Tags: javascript, json, chakram

I have an API response coming in this format.

```
 [{
 "response_data": {
    "0":{
    "id" : 0,
    "office" : "India",
    "type" : 'Perm'
    },
    "1":{
    id : 0,
    "office" : "America",
    "type" : 'Perm'
    },
    "2":{
    id : 0,
    "office" : "Europe",
    "type" : 'Contract'
    },
    "2":{
    id : 0,
    "office" : "Latin America",
    "type" : 'Contract'
    }

    }}]
```

I am trying to get all the `office` where the `type` is `Contract`. I have the json response saved in a variable like - using Chakram as

```
var response_json = t.body[0].response_data;
```

which gives me correct response in the `console.log` as

```
       "0":{
    "id" : 0,
    "office" : "India",
    "type" : 'Perm'
    },
    "1":{
    id : 0,
    "office" : "America",
    "type" : 'Perm'
    },
    "2":{
    id : 0,
    "office" : "Europe",
    "type" : 'Contract'
    },
    "2":{
    id : 0,
    "office" : "Latin America",
    "type" : 'Contract'
    }
```

Now how to get to the corresponding keys in inside the json and extract the information required. I tried this but it returns `undefined`

```
var length = Object.keys(response_json).length;
for(var i = 0; i<= length;i++){
console.log(response_json.i) //returns undefined
 console.log((Object.keys(response_json)).id); //returns undefined.
}
```

I know that this can be solved using `filter` method if the response was an array, but how can I do the same operation in JSON object? I am looking for an optimized solution because the API returns almost 5000 objects. 
If this question has already been asked, provide reference since I was not able to find any on SO.

Comment: That response is not valid JSON - all property names must be enclosed within double quotes, as well as all string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with filter method then
a workaround would be to add a property length then using `Array.from` like below. Then you can use `Array.prototype.filter` method.

```js
let o = {
    '0': {
        id: 0,
        "office": "India",
        "type": 'Perm'
    },
    '1': {
        id: 0,
        "office": "America",
        "type": 'Perm'
    },
    '2': {
        id: 0,
        "office": "Europe",
        "type": 'Contract'
    }
};

o.length = Object.keys(o).length;
let a = Array.from(o);

let r = a.filter(({ type }) => type == 'Contract');
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two major mistakes your code have one using `loop` up to the length of an `array` where index starts from 0. and second accessing an object from an array you use brackets instead of the `dot`. So update the code as follows:

```
var keys = Object.keys(response_json);
var length = keys .length;
for(var i = 0; i< length;i++){
   console.log(response_json[keys[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your response_json '0' , '1' all keys are in string format.
But in your for loop 'i' is integer so key is unavailable. just convert it to string you can get desired result 
like console.log(response_json[''+i])

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data =  [{"response_data": {
    '0':{id : 0, "office" : "India", "type" : 'Perm'},
    '1':{id : 0, "office" : "America","type" : 'Perm'},
    '2':{ id : 0, "office" : "Europe","type" : 'Contract'},
    '3':{ id : 0, "office" : "Latin America", "type" : 'Contract'}
    }}];

 var list = data[0]['response_data'];
    var filterList = [];
    for(var i in list) {
        if(list.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            var type = list[i]['type'];
            if(type === 'Contract') {
                filterList.push(list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

May be not better in javascript if the record is more than 5 thousand, better process it on server side.